# Handlebars.js Not Printing Object Key Value ( V4.0.5 )

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, handlebars.js

I'm running into a very strange issue. Handlebars does not seem to want to print a value from my object. I am printing other values from the object in my template, but it is returning blank for this one specific field ( and it's not an empty string). See Below. (network.colors.navbar is the field with the issue)

**Template:**

```
<script>
        window.networkInfo = {{{json network}}};
</script>
</head>
<body class="animated-content infobar-overlay {{ network.colors.navbar }} ">
    <div class="master-overlay" style="display:none;"></div>
```

**Output:**

```
<script>
    window.networkInfo = {"_id":"5744b94d4acb546c653cbf73","host":"159.203.100.31","name":"dexiMedia","email":"hello@deximedia.com","colors":{"brand":"navbar-brand-warning","navbar":"navbar-indigo","sidebar":"sidebar-indigo"}};
</script>
</head>
<body class="animated-content infobar-overlay  ">
```

The weird thing is, when I JSON.stringify() the network object right above it, it clearly shows that the value exists and is not empty.

I tested in both V4.0.3 & V4.0.5. I also tested triple curly vs double curly, and still same issue. None of the other fields have this issue.

**Note: The object is created from a Model.findOne from Mongoose.

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose was the issue. Not really a mongoose error, but a mistake on my end (colors.navbar was an ENUM that was missing that specific string constant). Hope this helps someone else as it is a very strange error.